# I would like to display the text of this file on my page. can I do this without printing out all the text in my code. this makes it hard to read?

Tags: html

I'm trying to put text on my page. can I input a text file?

```
  <div class="container">
    <input type="file" src="pone.txt">

  </div>
```

like this well not like this as this don't work, please help, thanks a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `embed` HTML element.

```
<embed src="phone.txt">
```

[MORE INFORMATION ON EMBED TAG](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp)

If you have access to a server side scripting language, it would be a little neater to do:

```
<div>
    <?php include('phone.txt'); ?>
</div>
```

If you want to use jQuery you can do it via:

```
$(function () {
    $.get('/phone.txt', function (data) {
        consile.log(data);   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an iframe inside of a paragraph to do it, like i am showing below

```
<p><iframe src="name_of_your_text_file.txt"></iframe></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily do that with HTML alone. You have to employ some JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<input type='file' name='pone' id='pone'>

<pre id='sameOutput'> </pre>    //this will render the text file as it is in the file directly on the webpage.


<script type='text/javascript'>
  document.getElementById('pone').addEventListener('change', function (){

var myfile= new FileReader();

myfile.onload = function (){

document.getElementById('sameOutput'). textContent = myfile.result;
}

myfile.readAsText(this.files[0]);

})

</script>

</body>

</html>
```